# $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_{1/n}^ne^{-x}\cos(\frac{\pi}{2nx})dx$

Tags: integration, riemann-integration

How can I prove $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_{1/n}^ne^{-x}\cos(\frac{\pi}{2nx})dx$=1?
I already proved $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_{1/n}^ne^{-x}\cos(\frac{\pi}{2nx})dx\leq 1$

Comment: Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a Schlomilch integral
Hence the result is 1

fjaclot;